# Regex get next 2 words after certain string

Tags: regex, regular-language

I need a regular expression, which can find names in some text content. It should match from 1 to 3 names, First-name, (Middle-name), (Surname).

I have a list of valid first-names which will be used to search the text. If the first-name is found in the text, the regular expression should get the next middle-name or/and surname, if they exists.

As an example the names below, should be valid names found:

- John
- John Doe
- John Average Joe

Special cases:

- John average Doe (if, possible it should match/find John Doe)

So far my solution is:

`\b(John|Mary|Tom)\b(?:(?:([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][^\s,]*)*[^A-Za-z]+)){0,3}`

This kinda works, the problem is the limitation to only match maximum 3 words, which this doesn't.

Online test: http://regex101.com/r/aM7bS3/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your regex [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/pX5bU2/3)

You can use the following:

`\b(Mogens|Victor|John)(\b\s*([A-Z]\w+)){0,2}`

Comment: Works great, thanks! Would it be difficult to extend this regex to handle the special case as well?

Comment: Yes, it would be difficult. It would probably be easier to have a separate regex for that.

Comment: Alright the above regex will be sufficient to handle my problem. Again thanks :)